# Selection / Filtering by kind

Tags: m2doc

I would like to select or filter scenarios by kinds in my Capella Project. When I use:

```
ownedScenarios.kind
```

It returns:

```
FUNCTIONAL

DATA_FLOW

FUNCTIONAL

DATA_FLOW
```

The first request I tried returns an empty set:

```
ownedScenarios->select(myScenario | myScenario.kind='DATA_FLOW')
```

The second one returns "ERROR: Couldn't find the 'filter(Set(EClassifier=Scenario),EClassifier=ScenarioKind)' service (78, 124)"

```
ownedScenarios->filter(interaction::ScenarioKind::DATA_FLOW)
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

interaction::ScenarioKind is an EEnum (an enumeration) and interaction::ScenarioKind::DATA_FLOW an EEnumLiteral (a value from the interaction::ScenarioKind enumeration) but the service filter() use an EClass as parameter. In order to filter on an EEnumLiteral you can use the select() service as in your first attempt:

```
ownedScenarios->select(myScenario | myScenario.kind = interaction::ScenarioKind::DATA_FLOW)
```